# Error trying to create a database with UTF-8 encoding and pt-BR.UTF-8 collation in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, character-encoding, collation

How do I create a database with `UTF-8` encoding and `pt-BR.UTF-8` collation?
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2, and it creates databases with `UTF-8` encoding, but with `Portuguese.Brazil.1252` encoding by default.

I've tried to create one with the following statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE "example_db"
WITH OWNER "postgres"
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'pt-br.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE = 'pt-br.UTF-8'
TEMPLATE template0;
```

but it returns the error:

```
Error: ERROR: invalid locale name: "pt-br.UTF-8"
SQLState:  42809
ErrorCode: 0
```

I want to set that location to resolve the error on Laravel:

```
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Comment: Try with 'pt_BR.UTF-8' instead and check if this locale is installed on your server.

Comment: @greg _"Try with 'pt_BR.UTF-8' instead and check if this locale is installed on your server."_
How do I install a new locale (such as pt-BR)? How do I do it?

Comment: What is your server OS? Please note the locale uses an underscore not a dash.

Comment: @greg Windows Server 2008 (local server)

Answer (score 0):

9To get a list of all collations available, query the [`pg_collation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-collation.html) system catalog. You can only use the collations you find there.

The collation you choose also has to be compatible with your encoding, but it looks like you are trying to do that anyway. Also, as an exception to the rule, you can use any collation with `UTF8` on Windows.

The error message you show is unrelated to collations, however. It must be an encoding problem in laravel — at any rate, it does not come from the database.

Comment: I want to do it to resolve the error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" on Laravel

Comment: I see. I added a paragraph to the answer, but if you feel the answer is not helpful, I'll delete it.